# Excel, matching column between two worksheets and grabbing different value of the match

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I've found different versions of this question but can't seem to get the correct formula inserted.

I have an excel file with two sheets (Classifieds, and Classified_Template)

The sheets share the column 'Title' which is column 'B'. The issue is the template has about 567 records and the Classifieds sheet only has about 530.

What I'm trying to do by putting this formula in the Classifieds sheet is find ONLY the rows in Classified_Template that have matching values in column B. IF they match, I want to put the value from column G in Classified_Template into the cell where this formula is. The ordering is all over the place between the sheets so I feel like it may need a lookup formula but that hasn't worked for me yet.

Also, in the formula the 'B2' is the first data row as row number 1 is headers

```
=INDEX('Classified_Template'!G:G, MATCH(B2, 'Classified_Template'!B:B, 0))
```

I would be expecting a date string here but instead I'm getting a 5 digit integer that I can't seem to find in these columns so I'm wondering if there is any issue in the logic of my formula based on what I'm wanting to get

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! What is the problem? You have not stated what's wrong with your formula. Do you get an error?

Comment: Thanks @ReddyLutonadio, no error but I'm not getting the matches that I should in the first few rows alone (it should be dates but I'm getting 5 digit integers that I can't find elsewhere). I'mn wondering if my logic is off

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio nevermind, I'm an idiot.....I had to convert the formula to date

Comment: Format the cells to Date first and then enter the formula.